# STUN binding request failing though IP and port are reachabe

Tags: networking, webrtc, nat, stun, turn

I am testing a WebRTC application that works perfectly well on hundreds of pairs of peers but fails on one specific peer (`Matt` below). Consider:

- `Alice` : Peer on which WebRTC app works (laptop on a home network behind a NAT)
- `Bob` : Peer on which WebRTC app works (Ubuntu server in a corporate network).
- `Matt` : Peer on which WebRTC app does not work (Ubuntu server in a corporate network)
- `Server` : An Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 instance I used for simulating `STUN` and `TURN` (more on this below)

The `STUN` and `TURN` servers used are:

```
stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478
turn:global.turn.twilio.com:3478 (with credentials)
```

**Issue**
`Alice` and `Bob` perform WebRTC signalling and `iceConnectionState` becomes `connected` within 0.92s.

```
[0.074] onIceServers: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
[0.081] createOffer
[0.161] onAnswer
[0.17] ICE STATE: new
[0.171] onTrack
[0.234] addIceCandidate
[0.235] addIceCandidate
[0.73] addIceCandidate
...
[0.928] ICE Connected
```

Now, `Alice` and `Matt` attempt signaling and `iceConnectionState` does not change to `connected` for up to 60s. If we wait till ~70s, the state changes to `failed`.

```
[0.143] onIceServers: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
[0.147] createOffer
[0.399] onAnswer
[0.408] ICE STATE: new
[0.409] onTrack
[0.541] addIceCandidate
[0.541] addIceCandidate
...
[15.528] addIceCandidate
[76.77] ICE FAILURE: failed
```

`Alice` and `Bob` each attempt signaling using identical code / stack with 100 other peers, and, in each case, the peer connection was established and the `iceConnectionState` change to `connected` within 2-3 seconds.

We perform the following tests on `Matt`

**Test 1: IP/port reachability**
The following works:

```
telnet global.turn.twilio.com 3478
```

This confirms outgoing TCP traffic to port 3478 and the twilio servers is not blocked.

**Test 2: UDP traffic**
I created a simple `netcat` listener on `Server` as follows:

```
nc -ul 3478
```

Then `Matt` was able to send packets to this server as follows:

```
nc -u <SERVER_IP> 3478
```

This confirms outgoing UDP traffic to port 3478 is not blocked.

**Test 3: Stuntman**
`Alice` and `Bob` are both able perform stun binding successfully:

```
root@XXXX:/# stunclient --verbosity 9 global.stun.twilio.com 3478
Resolved global.stun.twilio.com to 54.244.51.6:0
config.fBehaviorTest = false
config.fFilteringTest = false
config.timeoutSeconds = 0
config.uMaxAttempts = 0
config.addrServer = 54.244.51.6:3478
socketconfig.addrLocal = 0.0.0.0:0
Sending message to 54.244.51.6:3478
Got response (76 bytes) from 54.244.51.6:3478 on interface 10.1.13.185:47172
Other address is 54.244.51.6:3479

Binding test: success
Local address: 10.1.13.185:47172
Mapped address: 50.209.172.197:47172
```

However, `Matt` fails the binding test:

```
root@YYYYY:/# stunclient --verbosity 9 --mode full global.stun.twilio.com 3478
Resolved global.stun.twilio.com to 34.203.250.156:0
config.fBehaviorTest = true
config.fFilteringTest = true
config.timeoutSeconds = 0
config.uMaxAttempts = 0
config.addrServer = 34.203.250.156:3478
socketconfig.addrLocal = 0.0.0.0:0
Sending message to 34.203.250.156:3478
Continuing to wait for response...
Continuing to wait for response...
Continuing to wait for response...
Continuing to wait for response...
Continuing to wait for response...
Sending message to 34.203.250.156:3478
Continuing to wait for response...
Continuing to wait for response...
Continuing to wait for response...
Continuing to wait for response...
Continuing to wait for response...
Binding test: fail
Behavior test: fail
Filtering test: fail
```

The same test was performed with `stunserver --primaryport 8085` on `Server`. The outcome was identical.

==================

Have the following questions regarding `Matt`:

- If `STUN` server's IP and port are reachable and `UDP` traffic is not blocked, why is the `stunclient` request failing?
- What does the IT administrator need to do to allow STUN requests? What should my ask be?
- Why is the peer connection not being established through the `TURN` server? I can confirm the Twilio `TURN` server works. I'm seeing traffic from other peers on my Twilio account and the Trickle ICE test [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) succeeds as well. Isn't TURN supposed to relay traffic when `STUN` fails to find an external IP/port for a peer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a WebRTC project that was having similar problems. A Peer on a ubuntu digital ocean was unable to connect. What I found was

I had to open up the ports on the digital ocean fire wall. these are the ports I had to enable

```
#+BEGIN_SRC
  107  ufw allow 49152:65535/udp
  108  ufw allow 3478/udp
  109  ufw allow 3478/tcp
#+END_SRC
```

Note you want both `3478` udp and tcp. In my case I was using the [Coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) STUN/TRUN server and it was configured to run on this ports

```
    environment:
      - TURN_PORT_START=49152
      - TURN_PORT_END=65535
```

I think those are the default TURN range but not sure if `turn:global.turn.twilio.com:3478` is the same

I would check that port range on the `Matt` peer

Maybe you might want to host your own TURN server to examine the connections that are happening there as well.